# ng-bootstrap typeahead is hidden, looks like style top and left are wrong

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm having an input field and i'm using ng-bootstrap typeahead, but i'm not getting typeahead suggestions.

app.module.ts

[image]

search.component.html

[image]

search.component.ts

[image]

i have added search-component tag in app.component.html, but still typeahead suugestions are not shown, i tried to inspect, i could see typeahead-container tag is generated, but still i could not see it.
[image]

could any one help me, why typeahead is not visible? but i could use down arrows to select the typeahead - suggestions.

Comment: I would suspect mismatch of ng-bootstrap and Bootstrap CSS version. Make sure that you are using Bootstrap alpha.6 CSS with the latest version of ng-bootstrap. Here is a working plunker where you can compare correct setup with yours: http://plnkr.co/edit/MI2mOQzAe6raosOvrpQy?p=preview

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I just changed bootstrap CDN 4 to 3.3.7, and its working.I think there are some issues with alpha6 in bootstrap 4.

Comment: there are _no_ issues with Bootstrap alpha.6 CSS as proved in my plunker. Once again, you've got mismatch of ng-bootstrap and Bootstrap CSS. What versions of the 2 libraries you are using, exactly?

Comment: Same problem. Looks like .dropdown-menu has visibility: hidden for unknown reason